# NSString emoji literal

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, emoji

I'm trying to get the `NSString` for the smiling `emoji` whose utf-8 code is: `0xF0 0x9F 0x98 0x84`.
This works:

```
NSString *smile = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\xf0\x9f\x98\x84"];
```

but this doesn't:

```
NSString *smile = @"\uf0\u9f\u98\u84";
```

I get the error message: "`Incomplete universal character name`". Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing 2 bytes here. The \u expects digits of 4.

For example : NSString *s = @"\u0234\u0355\u0666\u0621";